# rails - creating a folder under stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

Under my app/assets/stylesheets I created a folder `components` because I like to create styles specific to each one of my html components. This way in my actual sass file (some_page.scss) I can just do a few imports depending on what I need.

for a visual, here's what the folder structure looks like now:

```
- app
  - assets
    - stylesheets
      - components
        _component1.scss
        _component2.scss
      application.css
      page-specific.scss
```

right now under `components` I have

```
_colors.scss // declaring colors for my app
_other_stuff.scss // other stuff...
```

usually when doing imports, I import colors first so that I can use them in the rest of my components. But rails is complaining:

> Showing /Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/rails/password-service/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> Undefined variable: "$green".

am I supposed to do something special to tell rails that I want my sass compiled in the components folder? or is this error being thrown for another reason?

by the way, here are the contents of my page-specific scss file:

```
@import 'components/colors';
@import 'components/inputs';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your *application.css* to **application.css.scss**

And then application.css.scss file has to be like below.

```
@import "components/*";
@import "page-specific";
```

Comment: thanks I'll try this and see. But now I have to include all page-specific style sheets every time I add new ones?

Comment: Put them in a folder like /application. @import "application/*";  sneaky_smile.gif

Comment: doesnt rails include only the page-secific styles for each page? so if I have a login_controller, and login.scss, only login.scss will be loaded for login/index. If I import all the files in the application folder you mention, all the styles will be loaded for every page

Comment: Asset pipeline will merge all your css files. You will have only 1 request for application.css. It will be loaded 1 time. Other requests will be read from cache.

Comment: If your specific css files have same elements, you have to give an id to your body and your css files have to be like #Home > div { color: #000; } #About > div { color: #fff; }

Comment: its in yellow in my question

Comment: Just put your common css files to under /assets/stylesheets/components folder and other specific css files to under  /assets/stylesheets/others folder and import "components/*"; import "others/*"; Dont forget asteriks (*)